# Is it possible to skip some records in query when you're only interested on a distinct value with PostgreSQL?

Tags: performance, postgresql

I'm sorry but I don't know how to explain exactly what I'm asking with words, so here's an example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2564a/1/1

```sql
    create table section(id serial primary key, name text not null);
    create table book(id serial primary key, name text not null,
                     section_id integer not null references section(id));
    create table author(id serial primary key, name text not null);
    create table author_books(
      author_id integer not null references author(id),
      book_id integer not null references book(id),
      unique(author_id, book_id)
    );
    create index on book(name);
    create index on book(section_id);
    create index on author(name);
    create index on author_books(author_id, book_id);

    insert into section(name) values ('Romance'), ('Terror');
    insert into book(name, section_id) values ('Wonderful World', 1), ('Terrible World', 1), ('Simple World', 1), ('Irrelevant', 2);
    insert into author(name) values ('Jill'), ('Mark'), ('Tim');
    insert into author_books values (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4);



    select b.section_id, b.name, a.name from book b
    join author_books ab on b.id=ab.book_id
    join author a on a.id=ab.author_id;

    select distinct s.name from section s
    join book b on b.section_id=s.id
    join author_books ab on b.id=ab.book_id
    join author a on a.id=ab.author_id

    where a.name in ('Jill', 'Tim')
    group by s.id
    having count(distinct a.name) >= 2;
```

This query brings the expected result, however I'm interested in knowing whether it's possible to change it to perform better somehow. For example, it's not clear to me what PostgreSQL will do in this case. For example, after evaluating the first book in Romance section that matches the criteria ideally it should skip the processing for any other books in the Romance section to speed up the query execution. Also, as soon as it finds Jill and Tim authors it should probably stop processing the other author checks since it already has the count(distinct a.name) >= 2 condition met.

Is there any way to help PG to apply such optimizations with changes in the query?

Just to be clear, the query's intention is to find all sections where there's at least one book written by both Jill and Tim authors at least.

Comment: "It's not clear to me what PostgreSQL will do in this case" => [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-explain.html) usually does a good job at telling you what PostgreSQL will do.

Comment: I'm not an expert on EXPLAIN but if I understand it correctly it will basically tell me whether an index is being used, what basic algorithm is being applied (hash, index scan and so on) but it won't tell me whether rows have been skipped or not by the engine due to some internal optimization.

Comment: The intention of the query is not clear. What do you want: find the authors who wrote more than one book within the same section?

Comment: I want to find all sections where there's at least one book written by both Jill and Tim authors at least. I'll update the description to make it clearer.

Comment: Books written by Jill _or_ Tim with another author will also meet your conditions.

Comment: I don't understand why. Could you provide an example? Here's the condition: " where a.name in ('Jill', 'Tim') ... having count(distinct a.name) >= 2"

Comment: My bad -- the inner join should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

The sort of nitpicky optimizations you're talking about are the sort of thing the query engine is meant to keep out of your hands. It's helpful to think of databases as operating on sets of rows rather than as inspecting results row by row: the engine retrieves all section rows, generates the product of section with book, discards all rows that fail to satisfy the `JOIN` predicate, and so on. The query planner can optimize things ahead of time by switching the order of operations around to minimize the number of rows it has to deal with overall, but it's not going to stop in the middle.

Indexing your foreign keys will help; indexing author.name will help; indexing section.name is probably pointless.

You could also create a materialized view from the query, if performance is more important than the results always being current.

Comment: Thanks, yes I forgot to add the indices to the foreign keys in this example.

This is just a simplification of what actually goes on with the actual queries I have to deal with. There are lots of tables and subqueries, sometimes involving the same tables, with several lines and the kind of optimization I'm looking for has the potential of greatly speed up the  whole query. It's not as simple as the example in my question...

Comment: None of that matters when the point is that database engines do not work in the way you are hoping they will. The only way to stop a query from looking for more results is to apply a `LIMIT` clause, but if your actual query has the same structure where your grouping key is at the top level, that won't help you.

Comment: I see, using LIMIT is the only way I know as well, but I don't know every possibilities with SQL or PostgreSQL. I was hoping someone with knowledge on the engine internals would be able to confirm whether the other comparisons are skipped in distinct selects when there's already an entry selected. I mean, if Romance is already part of the result set, I'd like to confirm whether the engine would skip any other rows in Romance section. Or whether it would be smart enough to not actually get the full count but only check whether it's greater than 2 and stop processing. Or any possible tricks.

Comment: Since you're applying conditions to entries in the authors table, it is unlikely that any optimal query plan will start looking for distinct section names until the end. And when it does, it still has to look at each row in order to ensure that, while it's already recorded Romance, it's not missing Jill's & Tim's horror series. But by then, most rows will already have been discarded for failing to match predicates, so there's not much to optimize anyway. The point remains: you are asking for something that sounds reasonable to people, but is nonsense in the context of a database.

Comment: This is a contrived example. In my real database, such optimization might skip thousands of irrelevant rows, that's why I thought about asking just in case I was missing something :) But if it's not possible, then it isn't :)